# Meizu pro 5 - Ubuntu edition in China

Tags: ubuntu-touch

As there is no delivery to China (what an irony), is there a way install Ubuntu myself (if I buy a Chinese version of the phone). I found no guide, and it is not listed on the supported devices (for flashing) either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Answered here [Yes there is a way :) ] http://askubuntu.com/questions/767323/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-meizu-pro-5-that-was-originally-with-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can flash the Chinese 64GB version phone.

You should use the steps mentioned in this post:
[How to install Ubuntu on Meizu Pro 5 that was originally with Android?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767323/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-meizu-pro-5-that-was-originally-with-android)

For step 1, which is only needed with a Chinese version, you need to make sure that you use the correct version of SuperSU and busybox. The versions that you can install from the Meizu app store do not work so you need to side load them.